# Take a list of file-paths and find which do *NOT* exist

Tags: file-management, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

Here's a bit of a challenge for you script-heads.  And by no means am I asking for somebody to "write me some software" -- I'm just looking for some pointers on how I might go about this.

I have a database table that stores some HTML data in a column.  Within that are several file-path pointers, such as  tags, which point to files in a specific folder on our webserver.  And what I need to do is, essentially, find any of those pointers (file paths) that point at a **non-existent** file, i.e. do not exist on our server.

So I can dump the paths themselves to a TXT file or whatnot, stripping out all the other stuff around them.  But from there, I don't know how to proceed.

And this is all in a Windows environment (i.e. SQL Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2, client workstation Win7-Pro).  And I've never personally used the Power-Shell, but I'm willing to try it if someone could just tell me A) yes this is possible, and B) here's how you might go about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Read the HTML with PowerShell. Parse the HTML with regular expressions, obtaining the file paths.  Use PoSh's Test-Path cmdlet to see if the path is valid.

Answer (score 0):

test-path is the command you're probably looking for. Test-Path -Path [SOME PATH] will return either a $True or $False value based on whether or not the folder/file is there.